# PHP/Regex recursive tags in html template

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing, recursive-regex

I'm using my own PHP code to render template files as HTML codes.
I need a regex to parse the recursive tags correctly, in this example it's the permission tags.

**Example:**
Template code:

```
<if condition="is_admin">
     Show this
     <if condition="can_do_this">
         Show this
     </if>
     <if condition="can_do_that">
         Show that
     </if>
</if>
```

I want to capture the contents inside each 'if' tag correctly, and of course without any nested tags problems.

I saw a Regex that will work perfectly on css:

```
/{(?:[^{}]+|(?R))*}/sg
```

However when I change to my format, it's not working. I've changed to:

```
/<if condition="(.[^"]*)">(?:(?!<if condition=".[^>]*">|<\/if>)|(?R))*<\/if>/sg
```

What should I change for it to work?

Thank you.

Comment: It seems like you're inventing your own templating language. I'd suggest you instead use something like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) which is built on PHP.

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML.  Use a proper HTML parsing module.** You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php or [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php) for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Comment: The question is *almost* a duplicate of a question from a week ago, with minor syntax adjustments: [`<if condition="([^"]*)">(?>(?R)|.)*?<\/if>`](https://regex101.com/r/nU5jA1/1). Please have a look at [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28392186/7586) for possible caveats. Also note that `/{(?:[^{}]+|(?R))*}/sg` works for nested braces and has nothing to do with CSS.